# Why is my Sheety spreadsheet only accepting the email

Tags: python

I wrote this code and so far it works but its only transferring the email data and not the first name and last name. Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests

ENDPOINT_SHEETY = 'https://api.sheety.co/74ad53c89414bcc19eeb7c5aad53ac64/flightDeals/users'

keep = True
print('Welcome To Flight Club \nWe find the best deals and alert you')
first_name = input('What is your first name: ')
last_name = input('What is your last name: ')

while keep:
  email = input('What is your email: ')
  second_email = input('Type your email again: ')
  
  if email == second_email:
    print('Welcome to Flight Club')
    keep = False
  
  else:
    print('Emails do not match. Try Again')
  
  
params = {
  "user": { 
    'first name': first_name,
    'last name': last_name,
    'email': email, 
    }
}


response = requests.post(url=ENDPOINT_SHEETY, json=params)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: You could also try binding `data` parameter instead of `json` by `data=json.dumps(params)`

Comment: Turns out all I needed to do was camelCase the json keys for Sheety to accept the values.